# How to include additional function in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I wanted to use the function 'substring-before-last' defined on http://www.functx.com. For this I added xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` statement at top and then tried calling the function using functx:substring-before-last. I am getting an error 'Unknown Function'.

If you have tried using the additional functions defined outside XSL, please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:import href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>` in your stylesheet to import the library respectively download that file and then import your local copy.

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWcDMef

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I am still getting error as 'Unknown Function'. I am using saxon 9 parser, please let me know if I should be using saxon 9.5 parser.

Comment: That error message sounds as if you use Xalan and not Saxon. If you still have problems then edit your question and explain exactly which version of Saxon 9 you run in which way (e.g. from the command line with exact command line or in an application with exact Java code).